# JQ - Remove Duplicate Array Values

Tags: json, jq

Edited for better clarity

I am using the following jq query to extract the AWS ARN and associated protocols. However I only need the ARN to be listed once followed by the ports and protocols

my code is `jq -r '.Listeners[] | (.LoadBalancerArn), (.Protocol)'` and the results are

```
"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde"
"HTTP"
"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde"
"HTTP"
"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde"
"HTTPS"
```

I have tried everything including unique, first, unique_by, select, contains, etc.. and the results are always "Cannot iterate over string" or number

Desired results

```
"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde"
"HTTP"
"HTTP"
"HTTPS"
```

Sample JSON

```
{
    "Listeners": [
        {        
            "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde",
            "Port": 9090,
            "Protocol": "HTTP"
        },
        {        
            "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde",
            "Port": 80,
            "Protocol": "HTTP"
            },
        {       
            "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde",
            "Port": 443,
            "Protocol": "HTTPS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the common field and iterate over the groups, then output the common field of the first (which is the same for the whole group), and iterate again to output other fields from the same group:

```bash
jq -r '.Listeners | group_by(.LoadBalancerArn)[]
  | .[0].LoadBalancerArn, .[].Protocol'
```

```json
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-xxxx-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/msword-123456789/20b73abcde
HTTP
HTTP
HTTPS
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6IS5cnXtpXz)

Comment: This is good but it only returns one array and I have multiple arrays. So I would like to see 1 ARN and multiple Ports and Protocols.

Comment: @eramm This should now show 1 ARN and multiple Protocols (and/or Ports).

Comment: amazing ! I never would have figured out all the extra brackets and dots.

Answer (score 1):

`unique` works on an array, so you'll need to create one with all the `LoadBalancerArn` first, then call `unique` and get the `first` of the remaining array:

```
.Listeners | map(.LoadBalancerArn) | unique | first
```

Comment: this is great but when I want to add to the results like .Listeners[] | (map(.LoadBalancerArn) | unique | first) ,  (.Protocol) I again get an error Cannot index string with string "LoadBalancerArn"

Answer (score 1):

Does this produce what you expected ?

```
jq -r '.Listeners |
      group_by(.LoadBalancerArn)[] |
      first |
      "\(.LoadBalancerArn) \(.Protocol)"
      ' input.json
```

Comment: It doesn't loop through all the arrays. I edited the question and expected results for better clarity

Answer (score 1):

You say you want the ARN listed once, followed by the ports and protocols. You don't give such an example, so it's unclear whether there might be multiple different ARNs between the items in the array of listeners. Let's assume that there might well be multiple different ARNs, and for that reason I'll use slightly different test data:

```
{
    "Listeners": [
        {        
            "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:BLUE",
            "Port": 9090,
            "Protocol": "HTTP"
        },
        {        
            "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:GOLD",
            "Port": 80,
            "Protocol": "HTTP"
            },
        {       
            "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:GOLD",
            "Port": 443,
            "Protocol": "HTTPS"
        }
    ]
}
```

`group_by` is the JQ function for collecting together all the items in an array that share a particular value for some expression. So you could use

```
.Listeners|group_by(.LoadBalancerArn)
```

to get an array of arrays of objects, where all of the objects in each inner array has the same value of `LoadBalancerArn`:

```
[
  [
    {
      "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:BLUE",
      "Port": 9090,
      "Protocol": "HTTP"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:GOLD",
      "Port": 80,
      "Protocol": "HTTP"
    },
    {
      "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:GOLD",
      "Port": 443,
      "Protocol": "HTTPS"
    }
  ]
]
```

From there you can safely pick out the ARN from the first object in each list, knowing that the rest must have the same value:

```
.Listeners|group_by(.LoadBalancerArn)[](first|{LoadBalancerArn})+{Listeners:map(del(.LoadBalancerArn))}
```

```
{
  "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:BLUE",
  "Listeners": [
    {
      "Port": 9090,
      "Protocol": "HTTP"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:example:GOLD",
  "Listeners": [
    {
      "Port": 80,
      "Protocol": "HTTP"
    },
    {
      "Port": 443,
      "Protocol": "HTTPS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's one AWS ARN and multiple values for Ports and Protocols